# Express the following matrix equation into a system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I am preparing for my Linear Algebra paper which is coming up in 4 weeks so I am working through questions in each paper.

I am puzzled with one question I have come across and perhaps someone can help me see the light.

Express the following matrix equation

$$x_1
\begin{bmatrix}
2\\
5\\
\end{bmatrix}+x_2
\begin{bmatrix}
3\\-4
\end{bmatrix}
+x_3
\begin{bmatrix}
-2\\2
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
5\\6
\end{bmatrix}$$

into a system of linear equations and show $x_1 = 2, x_2 = 3, x_3 = 4$ is a solution to the matrix equation and to the resulting system of linear equations.

So having an understanding of matrix multiplication and linear combinations I figure I'll go ahead and find the reduced row echelon form of the matrix by applying a series of elementary row operations.

\begin{bmatrix}2&3&-2&5\\5&-4&2&6\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}1&3/2&-1&5/2\\5&-4&2&6\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}1&3/2&-1&5/2\\0&-23/2&7&-13/2\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}1&3/2&-1&5/2\\0&1&-14/2&13/23\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-2/23&38/23\\0&1&-14/23&13/23\end{bmatrix}

I cannot see how I could get  $x_1 = 2, x_2 = 3, x_3 = 4$ as solutions to this matrix.

Please could someone advise if I am overlooking something here?

Thanks

Comment: You can choose $x_3$ aribitary. Then, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are also determined. Set $x_3=4$ and solve the equations using this information.

Comment: Clearly, your problem is that [the second row is supposed to have a $1$, not a $-1$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=reduced+row+echelon+form&rawformassumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22ReducedRowEchelon%22,+%22theMatrix%22%7D+-%3E%22%7B%7B2,+3,+-2,+5%7D,+%7B5,+-4,+2,+6%7D%7D%22&rawformassumption=%7B%22MC%22,%22%22%7D-%3E%7B%22Formula%22%7D).

Comment: @Peter No, his reduced row echelon form is wrong. Look at the link I sent you.

Comment: @NobleMushtak No that was a typo on my part which I have corrected. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint : Your final equations are

$$x_1-\frac{2}{23}x_3=\frac{38}{23}$$

and

$$x_2-\frac{14}{23}x_3=\frac{13}{23}$$

Set $x_3=4$ and determine $x_1$ and $x_2$. You get one of infinite many solutions this way.

Choosing another real value for  $x_3$, you get another solution this way.

Comment: This answers my question! Thank you.